# Is there an <ion-forward> equivalent?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have a new module that involves user entering information collected over 3 distinct pages.

Page1: some basic information with a continue button
Page 2: some other information with another continue button
and Page 3: with the final submit

I have  on Pages 2 and 3 - if I am on Page 2 and I go back to Page 1, the information I entered is still there (as expected). When I press continue to go to Page 2, however, the information I entered in Page 2 is lost and has to reentered.

Needless to say, I can store the information locally and bind it to variables on the html and all that, but I am looking to see if there is a simple, elegant way to do ion-forward - I would enable ion-forward only if the user has come from Page 2 to Page 1 - please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Form's data should be persistent for better UX**. Use an *Ionic Data Storage* to save all the information that you need in each step. Then you remove all the data when the form is submitted. The official documentation for [storing data within an ionic app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/storage).